# Strange output when printing the value 0x89 (-119)

Tags: c++, c, hex, output

As the title says, I get a "weird" result when running the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buff[4] = {0x17, 0x89, 0x39, 0x40};
    unsigned int* ptr = (unsigned int*)buff;
    char a = (char)((*ptr << (0*8)) >> (3*8));
    char b = (char)((*ptr << (1*8)) >> (3*8));
    char c = (char)((*ptr << (2*8)) >> (3*8));
    char d = (char)((*ptr << (3*8)) >> (3*8));

    printf("0x%x\n", *ptr);
    printf("0x%x\n", a);
    printf("0x%x\n", b);
    printf("0x%x\n", c);
    printf("0x%x\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x40398917
0x40
0x39
0xffffff89
0x17
```

Why am I not getting `0x89` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your `char` variables are signed and they're undergoing sign extension when being  promoted (upgraded to a wider type in this case). Sign extension is a way of preserving the sign when doing this promotion, so that `-119` stays as `-119` whether it's 8-bit, 16-bit or a wider type.

You can fix it by explicitly using `unsigned char` since, in C at least, whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation-specific. From `C11 6.2.5 Types /15`:

> The implementation shall define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char.

Sign extension does not come into play for unsigned types because they're, ... well, unsigned :-)

Comment: "_upgraded to a wider type_" you mean: promoted?

Answer (score 0):

char, by default, is signed - this means that numbers run from -128 to 127. Any number outside of that doesn't fit. If you changed `char` to `unsigned char`, you will get the numbers you expect.

Comment: isn't char 0x89 equals to -119 which is between -128 and 127 ?

Comment: `char` is not `signed` by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/char-is-signed-or-unsigned-by-default

Comment: Yes. 89 hex as a signed integer is -119. -119, when printed in hex, becomes ffffff89. The difference between 89 hex and ffffff89 is the difference between a char and an integer.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `memcpy` not a cast

```
char buff[4] = {0x17, 0x89, 0x39, 0x40};
unsigned int* ptr = (unsigned int*)buff;
```

**This is not correct**: `buff` does not point to an int object or array, so the cast `(unsigned int*)buff` is not defined.

The safe way to reinterpret `buff` as an `unsigned int` is with `memcpy`:

```
char buff[4] = {0x17, 0x89, 0x39, 0x40};
unsigned int ui;
assert (sizeof ui == sizeof buff);
memcpy (buff, &ui, sizeof ui);
```

When using `memcpy`, you have no make sure the bit representation you copy is valid for the destination type, of course.

One portable but degenerate way to do that is to check that the representation matches an existing object (beware, the following is silly code):

```
char *null_ptr = 0;
char null_bytes[sizeof null_ptr] = {0};
if (memcmp (null_ptr, null_bytes, sizeof null_bytes)==0) {
    char *ptr2;
    memcpy (null_bytes, ptr2, sizeof null_bytes);
    assert (ptr2 == 0);
}
```

This code uses `memcpy` and has fully defined behavior (even if useless). OTOH, the behavior of

```
int *ptr3 = (int*)null_bytes;
```

is not defined, because `null_bytes` is not the address of an `int` or `unsigned int`.

Comment: What do you mean "it breaks typing rules" ?

Comment: @j_kubik This use of `union` for type punning, in most cases, break the **type aliasing rules**. Here it may be OK (but some people would say it is not).

Comment: @Jonas In general, `union` has type aliasing rules issues, but `memcpy` is safe.

Comment: memcpy is not an improvement over type-casting the pointer: undefined behavior at pointer type-casting expresses our lack of knowledge about types memory layout. If you change the way memory is interpreted, or copy it bit by bit to another variable makes no difference.

Comment: @j_kubik It **is** an improvement. "_undefined behavior at pointer type-casting expresses our lack of knowledge about types memory layout_" No. The type-cast itself does not reinterpret bit representation, only the use of the resulting pointer does. Here the cast itself is incorrect. Of course, `memcpy` does not help you if you do not know what a correct bit representation for the target type is.

Comment: "The type-cast itself does not reinterpret bit representation, only the use of the resulting pointer does." Well, that's true, but only because such type-cast produced invalid pointer - using it will cause an error, but mistake was made earlier when getting the pointer in the first place. BTW such an union doesn't break aliasing rules.

Comment: "to check that the representation matches an existing object" - this is not a silly code, it's a useless code. It doesn't do anything. Copying memory into the variable and back is not a proof that binary representation is valid. These is no way to check for that, you only mix types for which you know that representation to be matching.

Comment: @j_kubik "_it's a useless code._" Of course. It is a just a proof that the behavior can be defined with `memcpy`. "_Copying memory into the variable and back_" is not what the code does. "_These is no way to check for that_" except the way my example does.

Comment: @j_kubik "_but only because such type-cast produced invalid pointer_" not sure what you can an "invalid pointer". Is `(float*)malloc(sizeof (float))` an invalid pointer?

Comment: Invalid in the sense - using it will cause undefined behavior. Could you elaborate on what your "useless" code actually does. I always thought that for `memcpy` (as according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) "The underlying type of the objects pointed by both the source and destination pointers are irrelevant for this function; The result is a binary copy of the data." So memcpy has nothing to do with binary representation of a type. Your assert will be always `true` - is that your point?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32785/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-j-kubik)